# Ways to test if an ip4 or ip6 is local?

Tags: networking

Out of curiosity im interesting in finding out which ranges are reserved for localhost such as 127.0.0.1 and more.

Comment: When you say "local" do you mean "defined to be local by the relevant spec" or "assigned to a network interface on this machine"? If I have the IP 1.2.3.4 and I ran this check should the result be "local"?

Comment: i guess you mean the address space to use in private networks!?

Comment: well my question was delibrately ambiguous because "local" by itself means different things to different people. Im trying to figure out whats "local" supposed to really mean...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> localhost as a hostname translates to an
>   IPv4 address in the 127.0.0.0/8 (loopback) net block, usually
>   127.0.0.1, or ::1 in IPv6.

Source (and details) : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost

Comment: interestingly java only tests if the first octet is 127 and ignores the rest.

Answer (score 3):

In reference to [RFC 1918](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918)

the so- called "private address space" for IPv4 is:

```
10.0.0.0        -   10.255.255.255  (10/8 prefix)
172.16.0.0      -   172.31.255.255  (172.16/12 prefix)
192.168.0.0     -   192.168.255.255 (192.168/16 prefix)
```

For IPv6 the block is called "unique local addresses" specified in [RFC4193](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4193) and begins with

```
FC00::/7
```

Comment: "private address space" and "localhost" is not the same. In doubt, 1918 addresses can even be assigned by the ISP, especially in mobile connections.

Comment: I know that but what should "which ranges are reserved for localhost" mean instead...!? local host is 127.0.0.1 to 127.255.255.254 and ::1 what else should be discussed about that!?

Comment: I think exactly that is what the OP wanted. But maybe he expresses himself wrong - which might make your answer fit again...

Comment: maybe I'll receive a comment from mP

Comment: @Frank Firstly my q was partly ambiguous and i apologize. However your answer is still interesting and worthy of note.